# The irq in kernel function asm_do_IRQ() is different from the one I request in module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I did some experiment with a cortex-A9 development board. I used gpio_to_irq() to get an irq num and I requested the irq and wrote a small driver with it , it was 196 in syslog . And  I added some printks in asm_do_IRQ.  When I triggered the gpio interrupt ,  the  driver works fine  but  the irq num in asm_do_IRQ was 62 .I can't understand. Why the irq number was different from the one I request? The driver is as follow:

```
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/interrupt.h>
    #include <linux/irq.h>
    #include <linux/gpio.h>

    #define GPIO_N 36     //gpio number

    int flag = 0;

    static irqreturn_t handler(int irq,void *dev_id)
    {
            printk("hello world hahahahahhahahah \n\n");
            return 0;
    }

    static int __init gpio_test_init(void)
    {
            if(gpio_request_one(GPIO_N,GPIOF_DIR_IN,"some test")<0)
            {
                    printk(KERN_ERR "Oops! BAD! BAD! BAD!\n\n");
                    return 0;
            }

            int irq,irq2;
            irq = OMAP_GPIO_IRQ(TEST_GPIO);
            printk("irq : %d \n",irq,irq2);
            // ..................
            // irq : 196 in dmesg 
            //......................
            set_irq_type(irq,IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING);
            enable_irq(gpio_to_irq(GPIO_N));
            int err;
            // request the irq ...
            if((err = request_irq(irq,&handler,0,NULL,NULL))<0)
            {
                    printk("err : %d\n",err);
                    return 0;
            }
            printk("gpio test init success!\n");
            flag = 1;
            return 0;
    }
    static void __exit gpio_test_exit(void)
    {
            int irq = gpio_to_irq(TEST_GPIO);
            if(flag == 1)free_irq(irq,NULL);
            gpio_free(TEST_GPIO);
            printk("gpio test exit byebye!\n");
    }

    module_init(gpio_test_init);
    module_exit(gpio_test_exit);
    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

asm_do_IRQ in arch/arm/kernel/irq.c

```
    asmlinkage void __exception_irq_entry
    asm_do_IRQ(unsigned int irq, struct pt_regs *regs)
    {
            struct pt_regs *old_regs = set_irq_regs(regs);
            printk("the irq : %d\n",irq);  
            //............... 
            // I get 62 here
            //...............
            irq_enter();

            /*
             * Some hardware gives randomly wrong interrupts.  Rather
             * than crashing, do something sensible.
             */
            if (unlikely(irq >= nr_irqs)) {
                    if (printk_ratelimit())
                            printk(KERN_WARNING "Bad IRQ%u\n", irq);
                    ack_bad_irq(irq);
            } else {
                    generic_handle_irq(irq);
            }

            /* AT91 specific workaround */
            irq_finish(irq);

            irq_exit();

            set_irq_regs(old_regs);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This observation is likely due to the mapping between physical and virtual IRQ numbers.  The numbers seen in your driver are virtual IRQ numbers, valid only when using the generic linux interrupt handling subsystem.  The interrupt number in `asm_do_IRQ` will be the physical interrupt number provided by the interrupt fabric of the core.

I believe the OMAP processors support interrupts on GPIO pins.  The way this is usually implemented is to allocate a single IRQ line for a bank of GPIO inputs, say 32 bits.  When an interrupt occurs on any of the GPIOs, that IRQ line will activate.  This is likely the number 62 on your processor.  If you look in the manual for your processor, you should see that IRQ 62 corresponds to an interrupt on a GPIO bank.

Now, the linux GPIO subsystem will allow you to allocate an interrupt handler to any of the GPIOs, providing you with a mapping from a linux irq number to a physical irq number.  The linux irq number in your case is 196.  The GPIO subsystem is configured to handle all GPIO interrupts (say interrupt 62), read the GPIO register to determine which of the GPIO bits in a bank could have generated an interrupt, and then calls out the interrupt handler you've assigned with  `request_irq`.

Here's a basic flow of control for a GPIO interrupt:

1. A change occurs on an interrupt in a GPIO bank.  IRQ 62 is raised.
2. `asm_do_IRQ` runs on IRQ 62.  The GPIO subsystem has been registered to handle IRQ 62 by the platform init code.
3. The GPIO subsystem reads the GPIO registers and determines that GPIO bit X has caused the interrupt.  It calculates the mapping from bit X to the linux virtual IRQ number, in this case 196.
4. The GPIO interrupt handler then calls the `generic_handle_irq` function with 196, which calls your interrupt handler.

There is usually a **static mapping** defined by the platform between virtual IRQ numbers and physical IRQ numbers. To see this mapping,

- enable `CONFIG_VIRQ_DEBUG` on kernels older than linux-3.4, or
- enable `CONFIG_IRQ_DOMAIN_DEBUG` on newer kernels.

Then have a look to `irq_domain_mapping` debugfs file. E.g. on PowerPC:

```
# mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping 
irq    hwirq    chip name        chip data   domain name
   16  0x00009  IPIC             0xcf801c80  /soc8347@e0000000/pic@700
   18  0x00012  IPIC             0xcf801c80  /soc8347@e0000000/pic@700
   19  0x0000e  IPIC             0xcf801c80  /soc8347@e0000000/pic@700
   20  0x0000f  IPIC             0xcf801c80  /soc8347@e0000000/pic@700
   21  0x00010  IPIC             0xcf801c80  /soc8347@e0000000/pic@700
   77  0x0004d  IPIC             0xcf801c80  /soc8347@e0000000/pic@700
```

Comment: +1 You can use the term *virtual* and *physical* IRQ.  However, it is actually more like a *master/parent* IRQ controller and *slave/child* IRQ controller.  Since Linux only uses one number and the *master* maps first, the correspond 1-1.  For other *chained* IRQs, typically start at an offset.  This is splitting hairs, and probably either way of looking at it gets you to the same point.  More importantly, `asm_do_IRQ` is only concerned with the *master/parent* IRQ controller.

Comment: @artless noise, that is to say, 62 is irq num on the master/parent IRQ   controller ,and 196 is irq num on the  slave/child IRQ controller.

Comment: @goodjesse Exactly.  Austin's description is correct, but *master/slave* might fit the structure of the code better; or at least another way to understand the same thing.  The GPIO module probably has some registers that act like a mini-interrupt controller.

Comment: @artlessnoise in my case, when I do request_irq with number X, this linux irq seems to use GICv3's INTID number Y(the /proc/interrupts shows it).  Actually this value Y is hardwired for my device. Then should I find the value X? And using gpio_to_irq maybe?(because qemu uses gpio to connect interrupts to gicv3)