# Can't access /proc/interrupts after free_irq

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, raspberry-pi

I am writing a kernel *v4l2* driver for an **ov7670 CMOS element** attached to **GPIO** pins on a *Raspberry Pi*.  I set up three **IRQ** lines (*Pixel*, *Href*, and *Vsync*)

Here is how I am requesting them:

```
ret = request_irq(  PX_IRQ, 
                    ov7670rpi_pixel_interrupt,
                    irq_flags,
                     "ov7670rpi_px",
                     ov7670rpi_pixel_interrupt);

ret = request_irq(  HREF_IRQ, 
                    ov7670rpi_href_interrupt,
                    irq_flags,
                     "ov7670rpi_href",
                     ov7670rpi_href_interrupt);

ret = request_irq(  VSYNC_IRQ,
                    ov7670rpi_vsync_interrupt,
                    irq_flags,
                     "ov7670rpi_vsync",
                     ov7670rpi_vsync_interrupt);
```

Now that goes fine:

```
#cat /proc/interrupts
           CPU0       
3:       4168   ARMCTRL  BCM2708 Timer Tick
9:          0   ARMCTRL  ov7670rpipx
10:          0   ARMCTRL  ov7670rpihref
11:          0   ARMCTRL  ov7670rpivsync
32:      68523   ARMCTRL  dwc_otg, dwc_otg_pcd, dwc_otg_hcd:usb1
52:          0   ARMCTRL  BCM2708 GPIO catchall handler
65:        543   ARMCTRL  ARM Mailbox IRQ
66:          2   ARMCTRL  VCHIQ doorbell
75:          1   ARMCTRL
77:       3439   ARMCTRL  bcm2708_sdhci (dma)
79:          0   ARMCTRL  bcm2708_i2c.0, bcm2708_i2c.1
80:          0   ARMCTRL  bcm2708_spi.0
83:         21   ARMCTRL  uart-pl011
84:       7436   ARMCTRL  mmc0
FIQ:              usb_fiq
Err:          0
```

Looks good.

This is how I disable the IRQs:

```
/* Disable Interrupts */
free_irq(PX_IRQ, ov7670rpi_pixel_interrupt);
free_irq(HREF_IRQ, ov7670rpi_href_interrupt);
free_irq(VSYNC_IRQ, ov7670rpi_vsync_interrupt);
```

I have also tried:

```
/* Disable Interrupts */
free_irq(PX_IRQ, NULL);
free_irq(HREF_IRQ, NULL);
free_irq(VSYNC_IRQ, NULL);
```

Both ways make it so that once the module is unloaded, I can not access */proc/interrupts*. When I try to `cat /proc/interrupts`, they system locks.

Comment: See [free_irq doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-free-irq.html).  Have you made sure the `irq` is disabled before `free_irq`?  The **NULL** will not work.  You need the same `dev_id` parameter as `request_irq`.  Also, the kernel version may help people answer.  Knowing about how *GPIOs* and interrupts work, I think you have the wrong numbers.  Did you define `PX_IRQ`, etc?

Comment: Ah the numbers could be the issue then. To be honest, I was using those as placeholder numbers until I figured out the proper ones. I suppose that could easily wreak havoc on the system if I just choose arbitrary ones? Yes, I defined PX_IRQ, etc...

Where does one usually find the proper available lines for GPIO? In this case, BCM2708

Thanks

Comment: Ah, it looks like [bcm2708_gpio.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-3.6.y/arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm2708.c) Provides a helper function to do just that.

actually, maybe not. I think that just initializes the catchall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use `gpio_request()` with your [GPIO numbers](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/gpio.txt).

```
 #define PX_GPIO 9
 #define HREF_GPIO 10
 #define VSYNC_GPIO 11

 gpio_request(PX_GPIO, "v4l_rpi_px");
 gpio_input(PX_GPIO);
 gpio_request(HREF_GPIO, "v4l_rpi_href");
 gpio_input(HREF_GPIO);
 gpio_request(VSYNC_GPIO, "v4l_rpi_vsync");
 gpio_input(VSYNC_GPIO);

 /* Now, gpio_to_irq() can be used. */
 ret = request_irq(gpio_to_irq(PX_GPIO), 
                ov7670rpi_pixel_interrupt,
                irq_flags,
                 "ov7670rpi_px",
                 ov7670rpi_pixel_interrupt);
 /* etc. */
```

[bcm2708_gpio.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-3.6.y/arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm2708_gpio.c) provides a *GPIO interrupt controller* as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871048/the-irq-in-kernel-function-asm-do-irq-is-different-from-the-one-i-request-in-m).  See also the [GPIO documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/gpio.txt).

Your primary interrupt controller **ARMCTRL** has interrupt 52 as *BCM2708 GPIO catchall handler*. This IRQ is *chained* and supports IRQ on each **gpio** line. The controller for the GPIO's will be listed differently in `/proc/interrupts` as **GPIO**.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I just found some fragments with this info, and I am working on getting it written.  Do you know if I need to call gpio_request(...) before free_irq(gpio_to_irq(...))?

Comment: `gpio_request()` is to *get the gpio resource*.  It is possible that multiple drivers may wish to use this pin.  This should always come first.  It is somewhat unrelated to the `irqs`.  Read the GPIO documentation for more info.