# how to configure the gpio.h file in order to request for irq

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I am using the LPC1788 evb cortex board manufactured by emcraft.
In that the linux source which is provided along with the board is not configured for IRQ.
this I came to know by seeing the /mach-board/mach/gpio.h file. but in my project I need to control the device using interrupts.
I am creating my custom device driver and the driver is unable to get IRQ number, as according to me this is due to gpio.h file  I feel.Please guide me to over come this issue.

thanks

any suggestion and links for reference are much needful to me.

Comment: Please read [Linux GPIO interrupt numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871048/the-irq-in-kernel-function-asm-do-irq-is-different-from-the-one-i-request-in-m) and [gpio.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/gpio.txt) kernel documentation.  If your board supports it, you should have macros `gpio_to_irq` and the like.

Comment: yes I have this macro but when I am requesting for an IRQ it giving me an error code -22, 
Is there any memory mapping like pin numbers to IRQ numbers is need be done for IRQ's ...??
IF so please guide me how to do..? as like in the gpio.h of at91
they have defined some thing like this
#define PIN_BASE  NR_AIC_IRQS
#define AT91_PIN_PA0 (PIN_BASE + 0x00 + 0)
#define AT91_PIN_PA1 (PIN_BASE + 0x00 + 1)
#define AT91_PIN_PA2 (PIN_BASE + 0x00 + 2)
#define AT91_PIN_PA3 (PIN_BASE + 0x00 + 3)
#define AT91_PIN_PA4 (PIN_BASE + 0x00 + 4)
Please guide me regarding this

Comment: as mach-at91/gpio.h my board gpio.h as not having any definitions like that.how to over come this please guide me