# Port B GPIO ep93xx/gpio.c interrupt issue

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, gpio

I am having troubles with gpio interrupt issue.
According documentation for ep93xx ports A, B, F can be configured to generate interrupts.
quote:

> Any of the 19 GPIO lines maybe configured to generate interrupts

However arch/arm/march-ep93xx/gpio.c is handling only interrupts from port A. And doesn't react to port B and F.

```
static void ep93xx_gpio_ab_irq_handler(unsigned int irq, struct irq_desc *desc)
{
    unsigned char status;
    int i;
    printk(KERN_INFO "ep93xx_gpio_ab_irq_handler: irq=%u", irq);
```

I know printk is terrible in irq_handlers.

I am configuring iterrupts via sysfs.

GPIO 0,8 are wired with Port F if it is important to issue.
Also when enabling interrupts on port B without having configured port A i get following warning:

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:103 gpio_ensure_requested+0x54/0x118()
autorequest GPIO-1
Modules linked in:
[<c002696c>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf0) from [<c00399d4>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x54/0x78)
[<c00399d4>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x54/0x78) from [<c019dd90>] (gpio_ensure_requested+0x54/0x118)
[<c019dd90>] (gpio_ensure_requested+0x54/0x118) from [<c019e05c>] (gpio_direction_input+0xb0/0x150)
[<c019e05c>] (gpio_direction_input+0xb0/0x150) from [<c002c9a8>] (ep93xx_gpio_irq_type+0x3c/0x1d8)
[<c002c9a8>] (ep93xx_gpio_irq_type+0x3c/0x1d8) from [<c0066ad8>] (__irq_set_trigger+0x38/0x9c)
[<c0066ad8>] (__irq_set_trigger+0x38/0x9c) from [<c0066e14>] (__setup_irq+0x2d8/0x354)
[<c0066e14>] (__setup_irq+0x2d8/0x354) from [<c0066f38>] (request_threaded_irq+0xa8/0x140)
[<c0066f38>] (request_threaded_irq+0xa8/0x140) from [<c019e784>] (gpio_setup_irq+0x14c/0x260)
[<c019e784>] (gpio_setup_irq+0x14c/0x260) from [<c019ec1c>] (gpio_edge_store+0x90/0xac)
[<c019ec1c>] (gpio_edge_store+0x90/0xac) from [<c01be8fc>] (dev_attr_store+0x1c/0x28)
[<c01be8fc>] (dev_attr_store+0x1c/0x28) from [<c00e8b2c>] (sysfs_write_file+0x168/0x19c)
[<c00e8b2c>] (sysfs_write_file+0x168/0x19c) from [<c009a3d4>] (vfs_write+0xa4/0x160)
[<c009a3d4>] (vfs_write+0xa4/0x160) from [<c009a6a4>] (sys_write+0x3c/0x7c)
[<c009a6a4>] (sys_write+0x3c/0x7c) from [<c0020e40>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
---[ end trace ff56c09a294dbe68 ]---
```

I am using kernel version 2.6.34.14 with linux-2.6.34-ts7200_matt-6.tar.gz patch (hovewer it doesn't seem contain patches for gpio.c or gpiolib.c)
cross version:

```
binutils-2.23.1
gcc-4.7.3
glibc-2.17
```

Also i crawled through change history of gpio.c and gpiolib.c and didn't find anything that can be related to this issue.

Can someone give me and advice regarding this issue? I want interrupts on all ports (A,B,F) not just A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of question on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinux-kernel%5D%20gpio%20is:question%20irq%20OR%20interrupt) (and [ARM irq OR interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barm%5D%20gpio%20is:question%20irq%20OR%20interrupt)).  Please look at them.

We can see many changes by looking at more recent [Linux 3.0 gpio.c change](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/log/arch/arm/mach-ep93xx/gpio.c?h=linux-3.0.y) logs versus the [2.6.34 logs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/log/arch/arm/mach-ep93xx/gpio.c?h=linux-2.6.34.y) and [the current version](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/log/drivers/gpio/gpio-ep93xx.c).  You should be able to get the current *Linux stable* tree and extract these patches and *back port* them to your kernel.  For instance, there is a **bug** where *port C* and *F* are swapped; I don't know if this is in your **ts7200_matt** variant.

Some important change sets to look at,

1. **arm: Fold irq_set_chip/irq_set_handler**
2. **arm: Cleanup the irq namespace**
3. **arm: ep93xx: Use proper irq accessor functions**
4. **arm: ep93xx: Add basic interrupt info**
5. **ARM: ep93xx: irq_data conversion.**
6. **ARM: 5954/1: ep93xx: move gpio interrupt support to gpio.c**
7. **[ARM] 5243/1: ep93xx: bugfix, GPIO ports C and F are swapped**

You may have **#6**, but it is worth looking at as it is basically the *interrupt* implementation for your controller.  After about *linux-3.0*, your SOC's GPIO controller was moved to *drivers/gpio/gpio-ep93xx.c*.  You may wish to look at these changes, but none seem to be related to your issue.  You should be aware of **structural changes** to Linux.  Ie, overall changes to *interrupt handling* and/or the generic *GPIO infrastructure*.  A good guess is that **Thomas Gleixner** or **Russell King** will make these changes.

The patches can be extracted from a particular *Linux stable* tree with `git format-patch b685004.. b0ec5cf1 gpio.c`.  This will create several *patch files*.  Move them to  your tree and apply with either `git am` or `patch -p1`.  You may have to massage these files to get them to apply cleanly to your tree; if you take them all, even though they are not related to *interrupt handling*, you will have better luck doing this automatically.  You can also look at the *patch set* and try to manually patch the file with a text editor.

None of this addresses your **specific** questions.  However, it gives a path to merge changes from the latest Linux versions.  Also, the previous stack overflow questions give details on the structure of the [**GPIO interrupt handling**](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/gpio.txt).  Coupled with your data sheet, the [Linux GPIO document](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/gpio.txt), and the given change sets, you should be able to fix your own problem.  Otherwise, you need someone familiar with the **EP93xx** and the question is fairly localized.

**Note:** The stack trace indicates that a **GPIO** is being used without a corresponding `gpio_request()`
.  This is either a bug in the *machine file* or in the *EP93xx GPIO interrupt handling* code.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871048/the-irq-in-kernel-function-asm-do-irq-is-different-from-the-one-i-request-in-m) may be helpful.  You don't need to search the *gpiolib.c* and *gpio.c* files but the interrupt controller infra-structure.  The code is linked by the macros `gpio_to_irq` and `irq_to_gpio`.

Comment: Thank you, i din't excepted to get exact answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same warning:

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:103 gpio_ensure_requested
```

From my research we have to call `gpio_request_one` / `gpio_request`, before `gpio_direction_input`.

It fixed the problem for me.

http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=99789

http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/p/119946/427889.aspx

Comment: That is the correct solution for the **stack trace**.  However, the original question is about interrupts.  I think the OP mentioned the **stack trace** to give more information; usually, it is not a problem, it just results in diagnostics.  It is good to fix, though (and is in the **note** part of my answer).