# What is the advantage of using GPIO as IRQ.?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, interrupt, gpio

I know that we convert the GPIO to irq, but want to understand what is the advantage of doing so ?
If we need interrupt why can't we have interrupt line only in first place and use it directly as interrupt ?

Comment: Maybe [this question on GPIO irqs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871048/the-irq-in-kernel-function-asm-do-irq-is-different-from-the-one-i-request-in-m) is helpful.  Also try `cat /proc/interrupts` and you can see the interrupt number for the *GPIO interrupt controller*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the advantage of using GPIO as IRQ?

If I get your question, you are asking *why* even bother having a GPIO?  The other answers show that someone may not even want the **IRQ** feature of an interrupt.  Typical GPIO controllers can configure an I/O as either an **input** or an **output**.

Many GPIO pads have the flexibility to be **open drain**.  With an open drain configuration, you may have a bi-direction 'BUS' and data can be both sent and received.  Here you need to change from an input to an output.  You can imagine this if you bit-bash [I2C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) communications.  This type of use maybe fine if the I2C is only used to initialize some other interface at boot.

Even if the interface is not bi-directional, you might wish to capture on each edge.  Various peripherals use *zero crossing* and a timer to decode a signal.  For example a [laser bar code reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode_reader), a [magnetic stripe reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card), or a bit-bashed UART might look at the time between *zero crossings*.  Is the time double a bit width?  Is the line high or low; then shift previous value and add two bits.  In these cases you have to look at the signal to see whether the line is high or low.  This can happen even if polarity shouldn't matter as short noise pulses can cause confusion.

So even for the case where you have only the *input* as an interrupt, the current level of the signal is often very useful.  If this GPIO interrupt happens to be connected to an *Ethernet* controller and active high means data is ready, then you don't need to have the 'I/O' feature.  However, this case is using the GPIO interrupt feature as *glue logic*.  Often this signalling will be integrated into a [dedicated module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Independent_Interface).  The case where you only need the interrupt is typically some custom hardware to detect a signal (case open, power disconnect, etc) which is not industry standard.

The ARM SOC vendor has no idea which case above the OEM might use.  The SOC vendor gives lots of flexibility as the transistors on the die are cheap compared to the wire bond/pins on the package.  It means that you, who only use the interrupt feature, gets economies of scale (and a cheaper part) because other might be using these features and the ARM SOC vendor gets to distribute the [NRE cost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-recurring_engineering) between more people.

In a perfect world, there is maybe no need for this.  Not so long ago when tranistors where more expensive, some lines did only behave as interrupts (some M68k CPUs have this).  Historically the ARM only has a single interrupt line with one common routine (the Cortex-M are different).  So the interrupt source has to be determined by reading another register.  As the hardware needs to capture the state of the line on the ARM, it is almost free to add the 'input controller' portion.

Also, for this reason, all of the ARM Linux GPIO drivers have a macro to convert from a GPIO pin to an interrupt number as they are usually one-to-one mapped.  There is usually a single 'GIC' interrupt for the GPIO controller.  There is a 'GPIO' interrupt controller which forms a tree of interrupt controllers with the GIC as the root.  Typically, the GPIO irq numbers are `Max GIC IRQ + port *32 + pin`; so the GPIO irq numbers are just appended to the 'GIC' irq numbers.

Comment: Ok I understand the point, because to provide flexibility these option are given. So that same pin can be used as a GPIO or Interrupt. Am I correct ?     
And how is GPIO lines intersects with GIC in case of configured as interrupts, are these GPIO lines connected to GIC ?

Comment: thank you for the details, its very helpful.
One last doubt I want to confirm that in the explanation:
master/parent IRQ controller  = GIC  .          

slave/child IRQ controller   = GPIO controller.   
Am I correct ?

Answer (score 3):

If you were designing a bespoke ASIC for one specific system you could indeed do precisely that - only implement exactly what you need.

However, most processors/SoCs are produced as commodity products, so more flexibility allows them to be integrated in a wider variety of systems (and thus sell more). Given modern silicon processes, chip size tends to be constrained by the physical packaging, so pin count is at an absolute premium. Therefore, allowing pins to double up as either I/O or interrupt sources depending on the needs of the user offers more functionality in a given space, or the same functionality in less space, depending on which way you look at it.

Comment: Ok I understand the point, because to provide flexibility these option are given. So that same pin can be used as a GPIO or Interrupt. Am I correct ?     
And how is GPIO lines intersects with GIC in case of configured as interrupts, are these GPIO lines connected to GIC ?

Comment: Yes - some users may want lots of I/O pins for data, others may just want to wire up lots of external interrupts. Neither want to waste board space on pins they can't utilise.

Answer (score 2):

It is not about "converting" anything - on a typical processor or microcontroller, a number of peripherals are connected to an interrupt controller; GPIO is just one of those peripherals.  It is also by no means universally true; different devices have different capabilities, but in any case you are simply *configuring* a GPIO pin to generate an interrupt - that's a normal function of the GPIO not a "conversion".

Prior to ARM Cortex, ARM did not define an interrupt controller, and the core itself had only two interrupt sources (IRQ and FIQ).  A vendor defined interrupt controller was required to multiplex the single IRQ over multiple peripherals.  ARM Cortex defines an interrupt controller and a more flexible interrupt architecture; it is possible to achieve zero-latency interrupt from a GPIO, so there is no real advantage in accessing a dedicated interrupt?  Doing that might mean the addition of external signal conditioning circuitry that is often incorporated in GPIO on the die.

Comment: Ok I understand the point, because to provide flexibility these option are given. So that same pin can be used as a GPIO or Interrupt. Am I correct ?     
And how is GPIO lines intersects with GIC in case of configured as interrupts, are these GPIO lines connected to GIC ?

Comment: I am not sure you quire get it.  A GPIO can generate an interrupt - it is still a GPIO (implicity an *input*).  The reference manual for your specific part will describe any platform specifics. I am not familiar with the ARM GIC, my recent experience is with ARM Cortex-M which have an interrupt controller called NVIC (Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller) - you were not specific about which ARM series or architecture.

Comment: sorry for mentioning GIC, I mean any interrupt controller. 
So just want to understand if GPIO is connected to NVIC in your case or not.
If GPIO_to_IRQs are just signals I expect they don't need any interrupt controller.

Comment: @SaurabhSengar : No the GPIO interrupt function requires the interrupt to be enabled and arbitrated by an interrupt controller like any other.  See for example: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0190b/CJAGBJIC.html